# React firebase duplicates data on first load but loads without duplicates on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, foreach, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a table that is populated with data after pulling the data. The issue is that on the first render the data is duplicated and the tables rows therefore have duplicates as well but when the page is reloaded, the data is no longer duplicated. Why is my data duplicating itself on the first load but not on the loads after?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { firebaseAuth } from './../config/constants'
import firebase from 'firebase'

class PeopleDash extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uid: '',
      people: [],
      peopleTableArray: [["name", "dateOfBirth", "height", "doneWithSchool"]]
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ people: [] });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user.uid);
        this.setState({ uid: user.uid });
        this.setState({ people: [] });
        var firebaseChild = this.props.firebaseChild;
        const ref = firebase.database().ref().child(firebaseChild).child(user.uid);
        ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
          snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            this.setState({
              people: this.state.people.concat(data.val())
            })
            console.log(this.state.people);  //ISSUE
```

**//ISSUE: at this point you can see the console log duplicates on the first page load but not any load after that**

```
          }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this));
      } else {
        console.log("no data");
      }
    }.bind(this));
    console.log('componentDidMount ended and this.state.people = ' + {this.state.people});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contentRow" id={this.props.id}>
        <div className="dynamicSnapshotTable">
        {
          // loop through each snapshot on firebase (for the user logged in)
          this.state.people.map((item, i) => {

            return (
              <div key={i} id={item.name} className="tableRowDiv">
              {
                this.props.tableArray.map((attribute, j) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={j} className="tableDataDiv">
                      {(this.props.tableArray[j] == 'doneWithSchool') ? (
                        (item[this.props.tableArray[j]]) ? ('tru') : ('fal')
                      ) : (
                        item[this.props.tableArray[j]]
                      )}
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              }

              </div>
            );
          })
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PeopleDash.propsTypes = {
  id: React.PropTypes.string,
  tableArray: React.PropTypes.array,
  firebaseChild: React.PropTypes.string,
};


export default PeopleDash;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` event may fire multiple times. Each time it does, you're adding more people to the display.

To solve this, make sure you just use the people from the query:

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
    var people = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
        people.push(data.val());
    });
    this.setState({
        people: people
    })
```

This also ensure that you call `setState()` only once (for each time the auth state changes), which will improve performance a bit.